# how do i solve this type of error in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I use L_F_W_O_P function in a class to make a `LabelFrame` widget in tkinter. When I want to use destroy method i get this error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

```py
Learning_frame_label_on_win=win.L_F_W_O_P(win,'Learning',0,0,400,600)


def L_F_W_O_P(self,L_F_W_O_P_main_frame,
                  L_F_W_O_P_text,
                  L_F_W_O_P_x,
                  L_F_W_O_P_y,
                  L_F_W_O_P_width,
                  L_F_W_O_P_height):
        
        if L_F_W_O_P_main_frame==win:
            self.L_F_W_O_P_main_frame  =  self.win
        else:
            self.L_F_W_O_P_main_frame  =  L_F_W_O_P_main_frame
            
        self.L_F_W_O_P_text   =  L_F_W_O_P_text
        self.L_F_W_O_P_x      =  L_F_W_O_P_x
        self.L_F_W_O_P_y      =  L_F_W_O_P_y
        self.L_F_W_O_P_width  =  L_F_W_O_P_width
        self.L_F_W_O_P_height =  L_F_W_O_P_height
        self.L_F_W_O_P_1 = LabelFrame(self.L_F_W_O_P_main_frame,
                                      width=self.L_F_W_O_P_width,
                                      height=self.L_F_W_O_P_height,
                                      text=self.L_F_W_O_P_text)
        self.L_F_W_O_P_1.place(x=L_F_W_O_P_x, y=L_F_W_O_P_y)
        self.L_F_W_O_P_1.grid_propagate(False)
```

Comment: Well, if you provide the full code we could solve your error. If you don't provide the line of code from which the error originates, then how are we supposed to solve it?

Comment: This code doesn't call `destroy()`...

Comment: `Learning_frame_label_on_win` is assigned the return value of a method that contains no `return` statement.  That makes its value `None` by default.

Comment: so what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes like jasonharper said, L_F_W_O_P does not have a return statement so it returns None by default, so if you were to try to call `Learning_frame_label_on_win.destroy()`, it would fail because Learning_frame_label_on_win is None.

I suggest to do the following:

```
# Create Label
win.L_F_W_O_P(win,'Learning',0,0,400,600)

# Destroy Label
win.L_F_W_O_P_1.destroy()
```

Also, consider getting rid of the L_F_W_O_P_main_frame variable and removing win from the arguments as it appears to be unnecessary since you can just call self (i.e. win) instead of creating a new variable.

Comment: i tried this but it destroy last FrameLabel that i made. but i need destroy frist one.

Comment: Learning_frame_label_on_win=win.L_F_W_O_P(win,'Learning',0,0,400,600)

ML_frame_label_on_win=win.L_F_W_O_P(win,'ML',400,0,400,600)

Comment: when I use the way you just mentioned i  destroy last LF but I need destroy First one

Comment: I see. In that case I think you would need to add a return statement to your original code. Try 'return self.L_F_W_O_P_1'  at the end of L_F_W_O_P on your original code.